# Iterate through Object properties to dynamically create an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I want to be able to print an array of `ICar` objects (for now just printing to the console) by iterating through a TypeScript file populated with mock data.

The `ICar` model, `car.model.ts`:

```
export interface ICar {
    Make: string;
    Model: string;
    Year: string;
    Specifications: boolean[];
  }
```

The mock data, `car.mock.ts`:

```
export const mockCars = {
    New: [
        {
            Make: "Honda",
            Model: "CRV",
            Year: "2021",
            Specifications: [
                true,
                true,
                false,
                true,
                false
            ]
        },
        {
            Make: "Toyota",
            Model: "Camry",
            Year: "2021",
            Specifications: [
                true,
                true,
                false,
                true,
                false
            ]
        }
    ],
    PreOwned: [
        {
            Make: "Subaru",
            Model: "Forester",
            Year: "2017",
            Specifications: [
                false,
                true,
                false,
                false,
                true
            ]
        }
    ],
    Used: [
        {
            Make: "Toyota",
            Model: "Corolla",
            Year: "2015",
            Specifications: [
                false,
                false,
                true,
                true,
                false
            ]
        },
        {
            Make: "Honda",
            Model: "CRV",
            Year: "2011",
            Specifications: [
                true,
                false,
                false,
                true,
                true
            ]
        },
        {
            Make: "Mazda",
            Model: "CX-5",
            Year: "2013",
            Specifications: [
                true,
                true,
                false,
                false,
                false
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Right now, my current solution primarily focuses on the data value associated with the `New` key in the mock data:

```
ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.getTestCars());
    }
    
getTestCars(): ICar[] {

        var testArray = []; 
        var testClient = mockCars.New;

        testClient.forEach(element => {
           console.log(element.Model + " " + element.Make + " " + element.Year);
           testArray.push(element);
        });

        return testArray;
    }
```

And the output in the console from my solution:

```
CRV Honda 2021
Camry Toyota 2021

(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {Make: "Honda", Model: "CRV", Year: "2021", Specifications: Array(5)}
1: {Make: "Toyota", Model: "Camry", Year: "2021", Specifications: Array(5)}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want to be able to take all the objects from all the keys in the mock data (in this example, the values from `New`, `PreOwned`, `Used`) and push them into the array as ICar objects such that the array returns a length of 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can take [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of the object and [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) it:

```js
const mockCars = { New: [ { Make: "Honda", Model: "CRV", Year: "2021", Specifications: [ true, true, false, true, false ] }, { Make: "Toyota", Model: "Camry", Year: "2021", Specifications: [ true, true, false, true, false ] } ], PreOwned: [ { Make: "Subaru", Model: "Forester", Year: "2017", Specifications: [ false, true, false, false, true ] } ], Used: [ { Make: "Toyota", Model: "Corolla", Year: "2015", Specifications: [ false, false, true, true, false ] }, { Make: "Honda", Model: "CRV", Year: "2011", Specifications: [ true, false, false, true, true ] }, { Make: "Mazda", Model: "CX-5", Year: "2013", Specifications: [ true, true, false, false, false ] } ]}

console.log(Object.values(mockCars).flat());
```